# DOM addEventListener: click works but not keyup

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a page where there is a table. Each cell should have a click handler and a keypress handler.

```
var c = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
  f = function() {
    console.log('key pressed!');
    if (keyCode >= 49 && keyCode <= 57) {
      this.innerHTML = (keyCode - 48).toString();
    }
    console.log(keyCode);
  };
    c[i].addEventListener('keyup', f);
    c[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log("clicked!");
    });
```

The problem:

The `keyup` handler never executes. The console never outputs 'key pressed!'. It could have something to do with the loop, although when I checked any SO questions similar, it had just the last element executing. In this situation, the click event works fine but the keyup event never executes, even when I used the last element.

Note:

I would prefer a non-jquery solution.

Comment: The loop is fine, though I'd put the `f` function outside the loop, and `keyCode` should come from the `event` parameter. What kind of element is a `.cell`? You should provide a full working demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<td>` is not focusable by default, it needs no input after all. But you can make it focusable artifically, one way is to set [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) for it. In fact I do not like this way, perhaps someone knows a better attribute (but it works).

```js
var c = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
  f = function(event) {
    console.log('key pressed!');
    if (event.keyCode >= 49 && event.keyCode <= 57) {
      this.innerHTML = (event.keyCode - 48).toString();
    }
    console.log(event.keyCode);
  };
    c[i].addEventListener('keyup', f);
    c[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log("clicked!");
    });
    }
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td class="cell" tabindex="0">I have tabindex</td>
<td class="cell">I have no tabindex</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

(Your event handler needed some fixes, related to `event` itself)

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks! Also, is there a way that you can block the focusing effect (blue outline)?

Comment: @forthe There is a [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) for that, [```:focus```](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afocus). All you need is ```td:focus{outline: none;}``` in the CSS. I rather do not add it to the example as here and now the visible clue of being focused is useful when comparing the behavior of these two cells.